# Delete not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
 }

 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws  Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");

}
}
```

My JS FILE:

```
$scope.del = function (record) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?')){
             $http['delete']('/camera/list/' +   record.filename).then(function() {
                 $scope.records.splice($scope.records.indexOf(record), 1);
          });
        }
      };
```

My delete controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list/{fn}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Record> deleteUser(@PathVariable("fn") String filename)    {
   System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting data " + filename);

   Record user1 = rep.findByfilename(filename);
   if (user1 == null) {
       System.out.println("Unable to delete." + filename + " not found");
       return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   rep.deleteByfilename(filename);
   return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
}
```

My Repository:

```
public interface RecordRepository extends MongoRepository<Record, String> {


@Query("{ 'filename' : ?0 }")
Record findByfilename(String filename);

long deleteByfilename(String filename);


}
```

When I click on delete button, it shows me this error:

```
DELETE 
XHR 
http://localhost:8086/camera/list/2fb1a2e020285cd91dc68a4fa7822151 [HTTP/1.1   403 Forbidden 14ms]
```

Anybody know what is the error? At first my delete worked but when I used spring security my delete is not working.

Comment: show us your spring security access settings.

Comment: Where is the access settings? Sorry at first my delete can work after i use spring security and the delete can't work at all.

Comment: if you don't know spring security at all, I suggest you to look for a basic tutorial before using it. Tipically, it has a configuration xml file (probably it can be also annotation-configured) where you can put your security statements. Look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/) and  [here](https://dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization). My guess is that you should enter an authorization rule for the DELETE verb associated with that URL. See the link I pointed out to understand how.

Comment: additionally, for details about discriminating upon http method base, look this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7347183/740480). It's xml-configured, but I bet there's something very similar for the annotation based configuration.

Comment: Can you see `Fetching & Deleting data " + filename` in console?

Comment: @Arpit i can't see it now after using spring security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to review your spring security config:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

When you say `anyRequest().authenticated()`, it means that all requests should be authenticated.

If you want to allow `camera/list` to be called without authentication add it to `permitAll()`

Comment: How should i write it?

Comment: Right now, my delete method is not supported after i add permitall() for my camera/list