# Disable Http-methods on Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am a little new to Spring security and need help to where I can disable the http methods such as OPTIONS, PUT or DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Spring interceptor url provides a method parameter, the down size is that it permits only a single method to specify.
You may overcome this by specifing few interceptor-url item for the same pattern

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
     <intercept-url pattern="/login " access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access=" hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access=" hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="POST" />
</http>
```

A different alternative is to write your own spring-security-expression e.g. isPermitedMethod the following [blog](http://www.borislam.com/2012/08/writing-your-spring-security-expression.html) may help.

See also:
 
[Using Spring Security, how can I use HTTP methods (e.g. GET, PUT, POST) to distingush security for particular URL patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347183/using-spring-security-how-can-i-use-http-methods-e-g-get-put-post-to-disti)

Comment: If OP want to disable the methods, it is enough to use `<intercept-url pattern="/** " access="denyAll" />`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a controller methods which only allows GET? Any other HTTP methods will be rejected automatically.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/releaseupdates")
public class ReleaseUpdateController {

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getRequest() {
      //do something, only accepts GET
   }


}
```

If you want to allow the other methods but only to a specific user/role, then you can configure those fine grained settings in a similar way to this: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/